# Is there a Python debugger that runs wholly under Emacs?

Tags: python, debugging, emacs

Is it possible to set up breakpoints and print variables in a Python program, all from within Emacs?

Comment: `pdb` works just fine when launched from `python-mode`. Try `M-x pdb`.

Comment: This is on my list for long now: https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1248657 Feel free to ping me ;)