# Pure black background in PyCharm CE and Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, pycharm

While my search for a Python debugger on Emacs remains [unfulfilled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162686/is-there-a-python-debugger-that-runs-wholly-under-emacs), I am giving PyCharm CE a test drive.

Already on my second day I'm encountering a trivial but frustrating point. Is it possible to set the background to be pitch black in just one place?

A program written by programmers for programmers should certainly have included a feature such as "change the background for Docstrings, Comments, Keywords, ... the whole shebang" to black, but I don't see it.

I understand of course that some parts of the UI will stubbornly refuse to change, and I'm OK with that, just so long as the Python code itself appears on a pure black background.

The Twilight and Mokokai themes come close, but their backgrounds still leave ample "contrast room" that could be used by darkening the background color.

[image: pycharm]
(How do we get from left to right... err.. I mean.. how do we get darker than we are.. um, wait... Isn't the version on the right so much easier on the eye.. but anyway, how can we do it?)

**Update**

The exact same problem and solution apply to Android Studio.

Comment: Are you just talking about the editor colors?  Not the panels and toolbar, etc?

Comment: @BrendanAbel That's right. That's why I hesitated before approving the edit to remove 'in Python code' from the title. I am perfectly happy if the remainder of the UI stays in this dirty-gray color, just so long as the code itself is perfectly legible (on black background).

Comment: I feel like I've read that a purely black background for light text puts strain on your eyes (more than just a dark-ish background alone), but I can't find anything backing me up on that... Anyone heard this before as well?

Comment: @Monkpit I can attest to the contrary from numerous personal empirical studies. Stare at the screen for 12 hours, repeat several days in a row. Do this once for a white background (the 'github' theme, say), another for a dirty-gray background (the 'Monokai' theme), and a third time for a pure-black background, as answered here. Then measure how much you crave rubbing your eyes at the end of each day. The result is that the first is worst (by far). The second is better. The third is best. No need for studies from non-programmers. But of course: YMMV.

Comment: @Calaf I'm not saying you're wrong, I just feel like I read this somewhere. I'm probably wrong because I can't find anything to back up my idea, though.

Comment: @Monkpit I didn't say you're wrong. I was just trying to convert you to the dark side :).

Comment: @Calaf Your opening line is priceless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `File` > `Settings`:

Go to `Editor` > `Colors & Fonts` > `General`

Choose the theme you want to modify (will likely need to `Save As...` your own as you can't modify the default color schemes.

Go to the `Text` > `Default Text` colors and change the background to black.  The only ones that won't be affected are the syntax highlighters that define their own background (usually select/highlight/errors/etc.)